# Upload the mp3 file in the folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to upload the mp3 file but it shows the message of :

> "The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file."

my file is only 4.5 mb and this is my controller:

```
public function add_audio(){

$config['upload_path'] = './musics/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3|3gp|mpeg';
            $config['max_size'] = '999999999999999999999';

            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            chmod('musics/', 0777);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data['audio'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];




if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    print_r($data['error']);    
    //line of codes that displays if there are errors
}
else
{
    $data['audio'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

    $this->load->model('main');
    $query = $this->main->insert('audio',$data);

    if($query == TRUE){
        $this->load->view('admin/success');
    }
}

}//end add
```

need help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini. After change, restart http server to use new values.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 5M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 5M
```

Comment: there are two file name php.int-development and -production inside my xampp/php so which file you are pointing can you make it clear plz?

Comment: There should be `php.ini` in `xampp/php/` directory.